# Setting periodic Live tile update

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro

I have been developing a windows store app, where I need something like

1. Periodically call a function that performs a http request and returns the response string
2. Update the Live tile with the returned string
3. These should happen only when the app is suspended/navigated away to start screen or something

(I have written the function to perform and return http request)

I referred to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868228.aspx) link but I do not know where to put those code in my program. Should I create a Background task separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set up a background task.  Simply make a call to `StartPeriodicUpdate` during your app initialization (perhaps after all of your UI has loaded).  Windows will then continually update the tile on behalf of your app using the provided interval.

Comment: periodic updates aren't that simple. you have to set up queued notifications, for example